# JUnit Tests for Java Mail Method

Tags: java, testing, junit

I tried to make my some first tests for my new Method, but i dont know, it seems that there is no progress, so maybe you could help me

This is the Method i want to test

```
public void sendMail(Student student, String currentSubject) {
    ReceiptData receiptData = new CustomReceiptData(student, currentSubject);
    String data = receiptData.create();
    Receipt receipt = signatureService.sign(data);
    File file = createFile(receiptData, data, receipt);

    String emailText = createCustomizedEmailBodyText(student, currentSubject);
    String mail = receiptData.getEmail();
    String subject = "Ihr Zulassungsnachweis zum Fach: ";
    sendMessage(mail, subject + currentSubject, emailText, file, file.getName());

    file.deleteOnExit();
  }
```

This is what i have now

```
package mops.zulassung2.services;

import mops.zulassung2.model.crypto.Receipt;
import mops.zulassung2.model.dataobjects.Student;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeAll;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSender;

import java.io.File;

import static org.mockito.Mockito.doCallRealMethod;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;

class EmailServiceTest {

  static EmailService emailService;

  static SignatureService signatureService = mock(SignatureService.class);

  @BeforeAll
  static void setUp() {
    JavaMailSender javaMailSender = mock(JavaMailSender.class);
    emailService = new EmailService(javaMailSender, signatureService);
  }

  @Test
  void sendMail() {
    Student student = new Student("272490", "snami100@uni-duesseldorf.de", "Amin", "Snur");
    String subject = "Informatik";

    when(emailService.sendMessage("snami100@uni-duesseldorf.de", subject, "Hallo, Test.", file,  );)
  }
}
```

Comment: So what exactly is the question?

Comment: i dont know how to write a test for this method...

Comment: What exactly do you want to test.. sendin message? deleting file? Why does your test doesnt do what you want to achieve? You have any error?

Comment: I'm to lazy to write an answer but have a look [here](https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-annotations). This is the stuff you need for testing methods like that.

Comment: i dont know how  to go on, yes i want to test how it sendin a message

Comment: You want to check the message the method is building and if the file is deleted. Mockito helps you to intercept whatever goes to ```sendMessage(mail, subject + currentSubject, emailText, file, file.getName());```. They you can check if it's what you expect it to be to given parameters.